# How do I add a constraint after I've truncated a table?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a script. The purpose of this script is to

1. Get all foreign key constraints on a database.
2. Truncate a table.
3. Re-Add the foreign key constraints that were removed.

I'm having trouble adding the constraints again [step 3] and I believe this is to do with the fact that my constraint conflicts with what is available. The data initially is...

authors table

```
1   Kenneth Graham  k.graham@twitw.com
```

books table

```
1   The wind in the willows Classic childrens story about woodland animals  123456
```

Authorbooks table

```
1   1   1
```

I have the following constraints on the authorbooks tables:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuthorBooks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Books_Author_xref_Books] FOREIGN KEY([BookId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Books] ([ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuthorBooks]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Books_Author_xref_Authors] FOREIGN KEY([AuthorId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Authors] ([Id])
GO
```

So when I try and add the constraints I get the following error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Books_Author_xref_Authors". The conflict occurred in database
>   "PeteDb", table "dbo.Authors", column 'Id'.

Is there any way around this and being able to add the constraint in regardless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use WITH NOCHECK instead of WITH CHECK to add a constraint that conflicts with existing data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529941/whats-the-difference-between-with-check-add-constraint-followed-by-check-constr

Perhaps you are getting the error because you "2. Trucate a table." and not all of them? Maybe you are removing the Authors or the Books and are leaving the records in AuthorBooks that references these other tables.

Comment: MATE! thanks, saved me a great deal of dissappointment :-) Thougth all my hard work was for nothing....

Answer (score 0):

> Re-Add the foreign key constraints that were removed.

You need not recreate FKs, as the truncate table does not drop them, but only delete the rows.

Comment: You can't truncate a table that is referenced in a foreign key constraint; therefore you must drop the foreign key constraints first. Hence the need to re-add the foreign key constraints that were removed.